# How to find the infeasible solutions faster with fmincon Matlab?

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am solving a multi objective optimisation problem. The pseudo code is as follows:

```
For h=1:10                     % Number of points
    1. Update some constraints % Update the constraint to find new points
    2. Minimize F(X)           % Objective function, is not updated at ittirations
       Subject to the Updated constraints.
End
```

For each iteration , a new solution is obtained. But, for some iteration the solution is infeasible and `fmincon` returns `exitflag` of `-2`. So, they must be discarded from the possible solution set of the problem.
 `fmincon` consumes a lot of time to recognise an infeasible point but for other points which have `exit flag >0` it is fine. Thus, the total consumed time of the problem is significantly large due to these infeasible points.

How can I set the `fmincon` `option` to get the infeasible points faster considering the fact that I can only set the option for 1 time.

Comment: Maybe you can do a first pass run with a low precision threshhold or low maximum number of iterations to screen out infeasible problems and then run a proper optimization on those problems that look like they will converge?

Comment: That's what I've thought too. But this might be unfair. @Dan

Comment: Unfair why? You'll have to tune the stopping parameters to fit your problem though...

Comment: Well, I have to compare my method with literature. They supplied Hessian Matrix and gradients to speed up their solver. some of them used another software like GAMS. But I modelled all of them in Matlab and used `fmincon` solver without supplying Hessian and gradient.  However, the contribution of my work is about the multi-objective method and not the solver. But 1000 sec may confuse the reviewers.  I think your suggestion is the only way and I will do that. Can I also, first run the problem and get the solutions , and then supply them as initial point for each point to the solver? @Dan

Comment: Are your problems unfeasible because of your choice of initial points or because they just don't converge? If the former, then maybe rather consider trying multiple initial points per run: http://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/how-globalsearch-and-multistart-work.html. Also, can't you compute the Hessian? You can give `fmincon` a Hessian...

Comment: It's a huge problem. 500 variables plus 300 nonlinear and tight constraints. it doesn't converge at all with a random initial points. I have some points that are obtained from solving this problem in a dynamic simulation software. Those infeasible solutions are due to the nature of the problem and not the initial points. @Dan

Comment: Then use a first pass to screen for infeasibility. I can't see how using a rough first pass to find initial conditions will be beneficial.